# Home Screen browser says not configured right - also no idea about current version

Tags: flash, fdt

I am very confused about my new install of Powerflasher FDT -- I have been using 5.6 for several years and recently upgraded so I could build my application with the ASC 2.0 compiler.
I am running on Windows 7 Pro, and the Home Screen has an outline of FDT 5, and a message saying something like the browser is not configured properly. I know my OS default browser is working properly, because the competitor browser is asking to change the default, and I even set inside FDT/Eclipse the browser to a specific (external) browser. No luck.
I don't even really know which version of FDT I have now, but I assume the latest, the plugins are listed as version 1.14.220.1724.
The FAQ and documentation are not helping me, can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!
-jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Your version is 1.14.220.1724. Released in week 22 of year 2014.
Your version is from 26.05.2014 listed here:
http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Release_Notes_%28Latest%29
It is called FDT Milestone 7.2

Comment: Thanks Steffi, do you have any thoughts as to why the browser is not working?